# How do I figure out this trig question algebraically and not graphically?

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve:

$\tan(\sin^{-1}x)$

I think the answer is $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

But I was only able to solve that graphically. I created a triangle on the unit circle, and since the sin is x, then 1 side is x, the hypotenuse is 1, and the third side seems to be $\sqrt{1-x^2}$

But how does one solve this algebraically?

I get up to here:

$$\frac{\sin(\sin^{-1}x)}{\cos(\sin^{-1}x)}$$

Now what? The top is $x$, but what does the denominator resolve to? and why?

Any thoughts on how to do:

$$\sin(\tan^{-1}x)$$

Is the answer $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

Answer (score 1):

If $\cos y>0$, note that $\tan(y)=\frac{\sin y}{\cos y}=\frac{\sin y}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2y}}$, so letting $x=\sin y$, $$\tan(\sin^{-1}x)=\frac x{\sqrt {1-x^2}}$$

The case for $\cos y<0$ can be solved similarly (take the negative square root).

Comment: This is valid for $y$ such that $\cos y$ is positive.

Comment: What about if the question was $sin(tan^{−1}x)$

Comment: try to write sin in terms of tan

Answer (score 1):

Let, $\sin^{-1}x=y$, then $x=\sin(y)$. Now, $\tan(\sin^{-1}x)=\tan(y)=\frac{\sin(y)}{\cos(y)}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

Comment: where does cos y come from?

Comment: use law of trigonometry. sin^2(y)+cos^(y)=1 for all y.