# How do you simplify this trig function algebraically?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

I have this trig function:

$$\sin(\tan^{-1}x)$$

How does one simplify this? I don't really get my book's approach and why we're doing it.

So I guess we're supposed to start by doing this:

$$\tan^{-1}x = y$$

so... $$\tan y = x$$

We're supposed to find the sin of that angle y, but how do we do this? Well, I have this trig identity: $\cot^2x + 1 = \csc^2x$... but I'm not sure where this gets me.

Graphically, I think the answer is $x/\sqrt{1+x^2}$ because if the tan of an angle is x, then that means opposite an angle there's an x, and then the other side is 1, and so the sin of that angle is $x/\sqrt{1+x^2}$ Is that right?

Comment: How is this different from [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2635166/265466) that you posted a few minutes previous to this?

Comment: it's the converse?

Answer (score 4):

$$|\sin\arctan{x}|=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{1+\tan^2\arctan{x}}}=\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
Thus, since $\sin$ and $\arctan$ they are odd functions we got the answer: $$\sin\arctan{x}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Comment: How did we get to the big square root sign?

Comment: I took $|.|$, which gives the sing $+$.

Comment: becase ur looking at $\sin(x)$ and not $\sin^2(x)$

Comment: I don't understand what is under the square root sign at all.... like where di teh 1 - <big_fraction> come from?

Comment: I used $|\sin\alpha|=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\alpha}=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{1+\tan^2\alpha}}.$

Comment: Under $\sqrt{}\,$ he put $1-\cos^2(x)$ and expressed $\cos^2(x)$ in terms of $\tan(x)$ using identity $\tan^2(x)=\sec^2(x)-1$

Comment: and then how does one get from there to the last step?

Comment: Because $\sin\arctan(-x)=-\sin\arctan{x}$ and $\arctan: \mathbb R\rightarrow\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$